# Laravel 5.5 redirect 301 from old to new url

Tags: redirect, laravel-routing, laravel-5.5

**Reason:** My website is indexed with old urls so I want to redirect until google re-crawls it. Once new urls are indexed I want to remove old url completely.

**Old url structure:**
I have changed a url and replaced underscores with dashes from

```
Route::get('{var1}_{var2}_details','');
```

to new

**New url structure**

```
Route::get('{var1}-{var2}-details','')->name('datails');
```

**I want:** to remove old url from my website completely and show only new url. How can I achieve that ?

Right now, I'am using redirect() on my old url;

```
Route::get('{var1}_{var2}_details', function($var1, $var2){ 
   return redirect()->route('details',[$var1, $var2]); });
}
```

When I hit php artisan route:list it show both routes. How can I remove old url ?

My website is indexed with old urls so I want to redirect until google re-crawls it. Once new urls are indexed I want to remove old url completely